# Irreducibility of a polynomial with rational (polynomic) coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and let $\text{Frac}( F[x])$ be the field of rational polynomials over $F$. Let $a = \frac{x^3}{x+1}$. Show that  $\text{Frac}( F[x])$ is an algebraic extension over $F(a)$.

I have this so far:

$x$ is algebraic over $F(a)$ since $x^3-ax-a = 0$, and thus every other rational polynomial is algebraic over $F(a,x)$ since if $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)} \in \text{Frac}( F[x])$ then 
$$ \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} * G(x) - F(x) = 0 $$
In simple words, if we can show $x$ is algebraic starting from $a$, then we can construct any polynomial starting from $x$ ,and then every rational expression would be solution to a polynomial over $F(a,x)$ Then $[\text{Frac} F[x]:F(a,x)] = 1$ and we get that $$[\text{Frac} F[x]:F(a)] = [F(a,x):F(a)].$$
Finally, I claim that this equals $3$ because $x^3-ax-a$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $F(a)$, but I'm not able  to show that it is irreducible. Can anybody help me?

**Shorter version:** Is this polynomial irrreducible over $F(a)$?
$$f(t) = t^3 -at -a$$
where $a = \frac{x^3}{x+1}$.

Comment: You don't need to show $f(t)$ is irreducible to conclude $F(a,x)$ is algebraic over $F(a)$...

Comment: Yes, thank you! but how can I show that it's degree is 3?